# Gfortran and glut utilities: why can't I link them into my executable?

Tags: opengl, fortran, windows-xp, glut

I am trying to get opengl working under windows (XP 64bit). I want to link a FORTRAN program with the opengl "glut" utilities. I am running this batch file script:

```
REM default folder
@set MY_DIR= K:\E_drive\My_openGL\

REM where the F03G binding is located
@set BINDING_DIR= %My_DIR%fortran_binding\

REM names of the F03G object files
@set MODULES= %BINDING_DIR%/glut_fonts.o  ^
     %BINDING_DIR%opengl_kinds.o  ^
     %BINDING_DIR%opengl_freeglut.o  ^
     %BINDING_DIR%opengl_glu.o  ^
     %BINDING_DIR%opengl_gl.o

REM the compile flags
@set FFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fcheck=all ^
         -fcheck=do -fwhole-file -funroll-loops -ftree-vectorize ^
         -Wsurprising -Wconversion -Wconversion-extra -static ^
         -I%BINDING_DIR%

@set FFOLDER= C:\Compilers\mingw-w64\i686-4.9.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev2\mingw32\bin\

%FFOLDER%gfortran %FFLAGS%   -c  RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.f90
%FFOLDER%gfortran %FFLAGS%  RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.o -static %MODULES%   -o randomsphere_freeglut_main
```

This script runs OK up to and including the compile command (second last one above). The link command (last one above), however, creates these error messages:

```
RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.o:RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.f90:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.o:RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.f90:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.o:RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.f90:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `glutSetWindowData'
RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.o:RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.f90:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `glGenLists'

(... 24 more similar messages about "undefined reference to" something starting with "gl" ...)

C:/Compilers/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev2/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: RandomSphere_FreeGLUT.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My interpretation is that the linker cannot find the glut utilities (I could be wrong of course!). I do have the dlls "glut32.dll" and "FGlut32.dll", but I am unable to communicate their existence to the linker (gfortran). 
I have tried many ways to get gfortran to find them, but have failed. 
How do I make gfortran find these glut utilities and complile them into my executable? 
What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of [-L and -l](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), for your case `-L/directory/where/glut/library/exists` and `-lglut32` (`-lFGlut32`)

You use mingw linker so additional information can be found on the [official page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)

Comment: thanks but that did not work. Both glut32.dll and FGlut32.dll are definitely in the folder K:\E_drive\My_openGL\. I changed the link command to iclude:   -LK:\E_drive\My_openGL\  -lFGlut32 -lglut32 

I get this error message:   ld.exe: cannot find -lFGlut32

Comment: if ld cannot find it, then there is no good library in the `-L` folder. On Windows you should have `*.lib` library present in the folder, `*.dll` is needed on runtime. Or do you use cygwin or something like that?

Comment: OK ; I hunted around and found glut32.lib and FGlut32.lib. I tried directing the linker to those folders (using -L\folder) as well as copying the lib files to %My_Dir% and setting -L%My_Dir%. Either way I got the same error messages as described above in the main text.

Comment: I do not use cygwin, just cmd.exe.

Comment: Try using `dependency walker` utility to see if the dll contains "gl*" functions you need for linker.